# Vue3. On a button click, call a method that swaps the data values ​and displays the data in a table, but it's not re-render

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

template

```
<template>     
  <div>
   <button v-on:click="staff(items,records)" >
      Staff         
   </button>         
   <button v-on:click="temp = records">
      Orders         
   </button>     
  </div>     
  <div>
    <b-table striped hover :items="records"></b-table>     
</div>
 </template>
```

I want the table data to be swapped and displayed in the table on button click. To do this, I created a method that takes two list objects as a parameter and swaps them. In the console logs, the data changes, but for some reason the data in the table remains the same. After refreshing the page, the data is filled with the original data and nothing changes

Script

```
<script lang="ts">
export default {
    name: 'Total',
    methods: {
        swap(items, records) {
            const temp = items;
            items = records;
            records = temp;
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            items: [
                { age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald', Тайтл: 'Macdonald' },
                { age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw', Тайтл: 'Macdonald' },
                { age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson', Тайтл: 'Macdonald' },
                { age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney', Тайтл: 'Macdonald' }
            ],
            records: [
                { age: 40, first_name: 'Фомин', last_name: 'Евгений', Тайтл: 'Macdonald' },
                { age: 21, first_name: 'Домолего', last_name: 'Захар', Тайтл: 'Macdonald' },
                { age: 89, first_name: 'Акулин', last_name: 'Александр', Тайтл: 'Macdonald' },
                { age: 38, first_name: 'Бобков', last_name: 'Илья', Тайтл: 'Macdonald' }
            ],
        }
    },

}
</script>
```

EDIT:
In some way i just can't get my $data in methods. I try

```
this.item
this.$data.items 
this.$data[items]
```

but every time i get error

```
TS2339: Property 'items' does not exist on type '{ swap(items: any, records: any): void; }.
    71 |         swap(items, records) {
    72 |             const temp = items;
 -> 73 |             this.items = records;
       |                  ^^^^^
    74 |             records = temp;
    75 |         },
    76 |     },
```

To fix that problem. I delete `lang='ts'` and it's start work.

**- If someone knows why "ts" does not work correctly, please write an
answer.**

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
        swap(items, records) {
            this.items = records;
            this.records = items;
        }
```

Your initial code only shuffles around values of local variables, but you need to change state variables

Comment: Property 'records' does not exist on type '{ staff(items: any, records: any): void; }'.
         staff(items, records) {
             const temp = records;
             this.records = items;
                 ^^^^^^^
             this.items = temp;

Comment: That is a typescript error, you probably have not set it up for vue

Answer (score 0):

Delete

```
<script lang = "ts">
//some code
</script>`
```

to

```
<script>
//some code
</script>
```

re-run serve

get back

```
<script lang="ts">
//some code
</script>
```

re-run serve

This works for me